# Getting wrong response from ksoap2 on android

Tags: android, web-services, android-ksoap2

I'm using ksoap2 library on android to connect to a web service. I run the following code:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, method);
request.addProperty("UserName", username);
request.addProperty("TransactionID", id);
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
nvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
ht.call(NAMESPACE + method, envelope);
```

As you can see above, there are two parameters. Here's the wsdl file for this part:

```
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="TransactionID" type="s:int" />
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="UserName" type="s:string" />
```

Problem is that I get different responses from the time I call it with same parameters from SoapUI. Here's how SoapUI request looks like:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:req="http://whatever.com/Webservice/Request.asmx">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <req:GetProduct>
     <req:TransactionID>id</req:TransactionID>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <req:UserName>username</req:UserName>
  </req:GetProduct>
```

Parameters name have an extra :req prefix that may cause my problem. When I add the req: to my java parameters name, an exception occurs:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://whatever.com/WebService/Request.asmx?wsdl/
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1345)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1339)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:993)
at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.openInputStream(ServiceConnectionSE.java:113)
at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:184)
at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:96)
at SoapCommand.invokeMethod(SoapCommand.java:42)
at SoapCommand.main(SoapCommand.java:16)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://whatever.com/WebService/Request.asmx?wsdl/
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1290)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderFields(HttpURLConnection.java:2129)
at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.getResponseProperties(ServiceConnectionSE.java:84)
at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:167)
... 3 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at SoapCommand.main(SoapCommand.java:17)
```

It's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code. The `req` prefix is as per SOAP/XML standards. The problem lies in the way the webservice is deployed and the way `ksoap` works.

All webservices are expected to respond back with the WSDL if you append `?wsdl` to the webservice endpoint. `ksoap` expects this and requests the WSDL. In this case, the webservice doesn't send back the WSDL, throwing a 400 error.

You should ask the webservice provider why the WSDL doesn't show up when you send a request for `http://whatever.com/WebService/Request.asmx?wsdl`.

If that doesn't work out, consider creating a SOAP client on a server, connecting to the webservice, and call your server with a REST webservice from Android. That way, you use less bandwidth and do less processing on the device.

Comment: SOAP wasn't designed for mobile devices. For simple WSs, `UrlConnection` works fine, but if you come across complex ones,forget `UrlConnection` even `ksoap` won't work. You will have to use REST.